# mongoDB servers are not available when the master is down

Tags: mongodb

I got the following errors when the master replica is down

```
ConnectionPool::PoolShuttingDownError (ConnectionPool::PoolShuttingDownError):
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure (Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:70117691586500 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="0.0.0.0:27017">]>
```

I have 3 mongoDB replica.

It seems the primary replica is  **172.19.16.109:27017**

I don't understand why I shutdown the machine **172.19.16.109**,

And remaining 2 replicas are unavailable to load data from its database.

Is it not making sense for the replicas ? Once if the master is shutdown, the others are also unavailable, too.

I expect that even if any replica is  down, the others should work correctly.

My configurations are as below.

```
vvtk_dqa:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "vvtk_dqa",
    "version" : 4,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "172.19.16.109:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "172.19.16.104:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "host" : "192.168.14.7:27017"
        }
    ]
}
```

## mongodb.conf

```
# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
#port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

replSet=vvtk_dqa
```

### isMaster

```
vvtk_dqa:PRIMARY> rs.isMaster()
{
    "setName" : "vvtk_dqa",
    "setVersion" : 4,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "hosts" : [
        "172.19.16.109:27017",
        "192.168.14.7:27017",
        "172.19.16.104:27017"
    ],
    "primary" : "172.19.16.109:27017",
    "me" : "172.19.16.109:27017",
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2015-02-11T02:05:12.021Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 2,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: After you take `172.19.16.109` down, can you log in to either of the other two MongoDB servers with the mongo shell? If not, what are the error? If so, what does `rs,status()` say?

Comment: And by `rs,status()` I mean `rs.status()` (was typing late at night)

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
gem 'moped', '2.0.4', github: 'wandenberg/moped', branch: 'operation_timeout'
```

to Gemfile helped me.
more info: https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/348